# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, jersey

Немогу решить следующую проблему.. 
  Из прочитанного мною по поводу решений этой проблемы я понял что есть   определённый конфликт между jars.. Немогу понять какой именно конфликтует.. 
Буду рад если кто исправит если я нетак понял!

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.<init>(Lcom/sun/jersey/core/spi/factory/InjectableProviderFactory;Lcom/sun/jersey/core/spi/component/ProviderFactory;Ljava/util/Set;Ljava/util/Set;)V
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:172)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:139)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:416)
at appl.test.ApplTest.main(ApplTest.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Вот мои Jars из Web Content..

```
hamcrest-all-1.3.jar
jahk2-api-2.4.0-b34.jar
hk2-locator-2.4.0-b34.jar
hk2-utils-2.4.0-b34.jar
jackson-annotations-2.3.2.jar
jackson-core-2.3.2.jar
jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar
jackson-jaxrs-base-2.3.2.jar
jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.3.2.jar
jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.3.2.jar
javax.inject-2.4.0-b34.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
jersey-client-1.0.3.jar
jersey-client.jar
jersey-common.jar
jersey-container-servlet-core.jar
jersey-container-servlet.jar
jersey-core-1.8.jar
jersey-entity-filtering-2.17.jar
jersey-guava-2.22.2.jar
jersey-media-jaxb.jar
jersey-media-json-jackson-2.17.jar
jersey-server.jar
junit-4.12.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

main method:

```
      import org.junit.Test;
      import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
      import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
      import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
      import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;

      import service.Service;

public class ApplTest {

private static final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/rest/calculations";
private static final String INT_R = "/integerCalculation";
private static final String DOUBLE_R = "/fractionalValues";

int integer = 12;
double d = 4.5;

         @Test
         public void main() {

     ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
     Client client = Client.create(config);
     WebResource resource = client.resource(URL);

     WebResource one = resource.path(INT_R + integer);
     WebResource two = resource.path(DOUBLE_R + d);

     new Service().IntegerValueService(one);
}
```

Comment: `at appl.test.ApplTest.main(ApplTest.java:25)` ну вроде как отсюда все идет. Неплохо было бы код увидеть. Смотрим что там - видимо что-то связанное наврено с `Client`. Смотрим откуда делается импорт конфликтного класса.  `jersey-client-1.0.3.jar
jersey-client.jar` это случаем не один и тот же джарник?

Comment: Smirnov я добавил метод с импортами.

Comment: удали один из этих джарников  и проверь наконец-то!

Comment: @Maks.Burkov , я упомянул 2 джарника которые вроде как одинаковые, просто в одном не проставлена версия. Удали один из них (который без версии наверно)  и проверь.

Comment: Цовак Саакян .. расслабься я понял..

Comment: Smirnov спасибо я проверю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jersey-client-1.0.3.jar 
jersey-client.jar
```

По все видимости проблема здесь. 
содержимое джарников одно и то же, поэтому программа не может понять откуда использовать классы. Поэтому кидает исключение `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`

Уберите `jersey-client.jar` и проверьте.

Comment: После удаления jersey-client.jar я получаю обсолютно ту же ошибку.. В чём может быть еше дело ?

Comment: Похожий случай.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591811/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror.. Возможно неправельная версия jar файла.. 
Не пойму как узнать какого именно jar файла.. ?

Comment: Smirnov. Хотел также тебя спросить. Я как новичок немогу понять как читать этот лог ошибок который выскакивает, для того чтобы самому разобратся и незакидывать форум вопросами.. Если есть какойто линк к тому как правильно читать лог ошибок буду рад если скинеш.

Comment: @Maks.Burkov , ну [вот нашел](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) на английском правда. Но вроде как и тут попадалась на глаза подобная тема. А вообще все гуглится по типу "как читать stack trace" ну можно еще указать язык программирования)

Comment: @Maks.Burkov ,  а джарники добавляешь ручками или через maven или подобное? Есть еще предположение, что просто не все необходимы джарники добавил.

Comment: джарики добавляю ручками. Спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: @Maks.Burkov тогда советую почитать про средства автоматизации сборки проектов - maven или gradle (первый возможно будет попроще) . Инструменты которые довольно сильно упрощают жизнь). А по сабжу порыл еще инфы, может просто еще заново надо перекомпилировать весь проект, т.к. в `classpath` могли остаться лишние файлы, которые и губят все - инфа из англоязычного стака)